# How to find names of rows of all equal values in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
             col2  col3  col4  col5  col6 
    row2     2      0    1004   0    200
    row3     0      0     0     0     0
    row4     0      0     0     0    57
    row5     1      22    67    11   303
    row6     0      0     0     0     0
    row7     1      2     3     4     5
    row8     3      3     3     3     3
```

I would like to have printed or identified the names of the rows that have all zeros after them. For the above example, output should be:

```
    row3
    row6
```

as these are the names of the only rows with all zeros after the first (name) cell.

Below is code of how I think these names (subset of column 1) could be found.

```
    // Setting the variables for the above example
    common_char = 0
    num_rows = 8;
    num_columns = 6;

    boolean show = true;

    for x in range (2 , num_rows):

        for y in range (2 , num_columns):

            if (cell[x,y] != common_char):
                show = false

        if (show == true):
            print cell[x,1]

        show = true

    end
```

How should I implement this with Excel?

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Test()
    Dim common_char As Long, num_rows As Long, num_Columns As Long, iRow As Range, loopRange As Range
    common_char = 0
    num_rows = 7                                 '8
    num_Columns = 5                              '6
    With ActiveSheet
        Set loopRange = .Cells(2, 2).Resize(num_rows, num_Columns)
        For Each iRow In loopRange.Rows
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(iRow, common_char) = num_Columns Then
                MsgBox iRow.Address
            End If
        Next iRow
    End With
End Sub
```

This works for data laid out as follows, therefore I have removed 1 from both num_rows and num_columns to account for actual data range.

[image: data]

Comment: Thank you this is helpful as it locates all of the desired rows. I redirected output to a column on another sheet so that I could read the names of the rows with all zeros.